# Auto run a sh script when EC2 Linux start/reboot

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have put Tomcat to EC2 Linux. I can start tomcat by running a script:

```
$ sh starttc.sh
```

How can I config EC2 to run this script to start Tomcat when EC2 instance reboot?
I know little about Linux.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I already have an instance. The question is about running this script whenever this instance reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [User-data script](https://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts/) for this.